# mod_rewrite new URL for pages plus wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change the domain for both a wordpress and a number of hand-coded pages.

Is there a way to write something in .htaccess so that www.olddomain.com/* goes to the corresponding www.newdomain.com/* for everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a proper 301 redirect so that search engines will know to start indexing the new domain... something like this should worK if applied before the rest of the rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^olddomain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want everything redirected permanently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```